# Universal windows IoT app build failing in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-iot-core-10

Am not able to build the Universal windows app in Visual studio 2015,Getting build error as "Task 'GenerateAppxPackageRecipe' failed. 0x7F - Failed to load MRM support library." Can someone help me with this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what's the result if you try to build a simple Universal windows app?

Comment: I am getting the same error for simple universal windows app(created blank solution and trying to build). Seems like there is some something wrong in the Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets file.

Comment: The simple universal windows app has the same issue, you may repair your VS.

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows 10? 8 ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a Windows 7 SP1 64-bit machine.  This started immediately after I updated to VS2015 update 3.  I've done repairs and re-installed VS2015 and I still get the error is a blank/new UWP app.  I'm even targeting the older SDK 10586 as both min and target version.

Comment: I am getting this error too after update VS to latest version (Update 3). The problem happens only on our build server with Windows Server 2008R2. On another computer with Windows 10, the same project, same version of VS, it builds without problem.

Comment: @James Win7 is not supported https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: @Bart - Indeed, I saw that as well.  Unfortunately, the project doesn't build event if I target an earlier SDK.  I'm beginning to think VS 2015 Update 3 itself doesn't build store apps on Windows 7 PC's when Update 2 did without problems.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried to reinstall and repair visual studio 2015, it didnt work in windows 7. I installed VS2015 in another windows 7 machine where VS 2013 was installed previously without unistalling and it worked. So, assuming there is some package missing in Win 7.

Comment: Make sure the platform is set to Any CPU in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Windows 10 SDK (ver. 10.0.14393.33) which is included in Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3. And it has been fixed in **QFE Build 10.0.14393.795**.

> This non-security update includes quality improvements:
>
> - **Addressed issue where developers could not build UWP apps on Windows 7 because MRMSupport.dll failed to load.**
> - Addressed issue where MidlRT and MDMerge failed to run on Windows 7
> - Addressed issue where SDK setup failed to install on Windows
> - Addressed issue where deploying a legacy Store app to a 8.1 Phone caused Visual Studio to crash
> - Addressed issue where application data was not preserved across remote debugging sessions when apps were getting un-registered

For more info, please see [Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

To solve this problem, please go to *Add/Remove Programs* and Uninstall **Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.14393.33**. Then reinstall the  [10.0.14393.795 version](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=838916) from *Windows SDK and emulator archive*. After this, you should be able to build the UWP app with no error.

However, on Windows 7, with Visual Studio 2015, the official support for Windows Universal is "**Build only**". A lot of other Visual Studio features are degraded. So if you are developing Windows Universal Apps, **Windows 10 is strongly recommended**. For more info, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42824713).