# Remote debug UWP app on Windows Server 2016

Tags: deployment, uwp, remote-debugging, windows-server-2016

### The goal

I would like to use a Windows Server 2016 (x64) for remote debugging of UWP applications. The reason? My working PC still runs a Windows 7 instance and it is not possible to deploy an UWP app on a Windows 7 machine.

### The problem

I have already installed the Remote Tools For Visual Studio 2015 on the Windows Server 2016 machine and started it on port 4020. Authentication mode was set to "None". I have enabled Developer mode on the server as well. Also I have set up my project in Visual Studio to use the remote machine for debugging.

The problem is, whenever I try to deploy (just deploy, not even debug) my solution to the server, the following happens:

Visual Studio shows the following output:

```
Deploy started: Project: MyProject.UI.Uwp, Configuration: Debug x86
Starting remote deployment...
Reading package recipe file "C:\SourceCode\MyProject\MyProject.UI.Uwp\bin\x86\Debug\MyProject.UI.Uwp.build.appxrecipe"...
```

and **then hangs forever**.

In the meantime, remote tools on the server show the following output:

```
UserAbc connected.
```

This indicates there must be at least some communication between my Windows 7 PC and the target Windows Server 2016 machine.

No error message is displayed whatsoever (neither in Visual Studio, nor in the Remote Debugger).

### The question

Any idea why the deployment hangs forever without an error message? Or am I trying to achieve an impossible task? Is the Windows Server 2016 capable of running UWP apps at all?

### Update

I installed VS 2015 Update 3 directly on the Windows Server 2016. I was able to create and debug a simple UWP app directly on the server so the server is clearly able to run an UWP app. However I am still unable to make the remote debugging working. Maybe the problem is completely on my local Windows 7 PC and has nothing to do with the Windows Server. It is strange that the process hangs while "Reading package recipe file". Could it be that an antivirus is intercepting?

Comment: No I don't think UWP apps run on windows server 2016

Comment: @KenTucker I believe you are right, a default server installation only has the core installed which will not allow desktop apps to run. You need to install the desktop experience to enable this.

Comment: @SilentStorm, good point, however we have got a version with Desktop Experience.

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using on Windows 7? I think this issue may related to your Windows 7 environment.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, it is Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - corresponding to the Remote Tools version on the Windows Server.

Comment: In my experience, In 2015, I've developed and debugged my uwp app with Win7 dev system with VS2015 RC and Win10 target system. it worked well. @Anton, have you tried to remote debug non-uwp app - like as simple winforms App? If it also failed, it may be a generic remote debug issue, not uwp specific one.

Comment: Have you checked the package recipe file? Do you have this file under "C:\SourceCode\MyProject\MyProject.UI.Uwp\bin\x86\Debug\MyProject.UI.Uwp.build.appxrecipe"？

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, thank you for the suggestion - yes, the file is there. Should I look for anything specific inside the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. There is a similar issue when I try to deploy the UWP project to a remote machine on Windows 7. We have communicated about this using our internal channel. Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017 doing UWP development on Windows 7 is not a recommend scenario.

For Visual Studio 2017, using Tools for UWP App Development is not applicable on Windows 7. See [Visual Studio 2017 Support for Windows Development](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs#a-iddevelopwindows-avisual-studio-2017-support-for-windows-development).

For Visual Studio 2015, the official support for Windows Universal is "**Build only**". We can use Visual Studio 2015 to build UWP apps on Windows 7, but some other Visual Studio features for Windows Universal development may be degraded. See [Visual Studio 2015 Support for Windows Universal, Windows Store, and Windows Phone App Development](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-compatibility-vs#visual-studio-2015-support-for-windows-universal-windows-store-and-windows-phone-app-development).

To develop Windows Universal Apps, **Windows 10 is strongly recommended**. With Windows 10, you can get the best experience of UWP development.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation and feedback. Highly appreciated even though I had hoped for better news.